# Check if folders exist in Git repository... testing if a sub-string exists in bash with NULL as a separator

Tags: bash, git, regex

I have a common git "post-receive" script for several projects, and it needs to perform different actions if an /app/ or /public/ folder exists in the root.

Using:

```
FOLDERS=`git ls-tree -d --name-only -z master`;
```

I can see the directory listing, and I would like to use the RegExp support in bash to run something like:

```
if [[ "$FOLDERS" =~ app ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

But that won't work if there was something like an "**app** lication" folder... I specified the "-z" option in the git "ls-tree" command so I could use the \0 (null) character as a separator, but not sure how to test for that in the bash RegExp.

Likewise I know there is support for specifying a particular path in the ls-tree command, and could then pipe that to "wc -l", but I'd have thought it was quicker to get a full directory listing of the root (not recursive) then test for the 2 (or more) folders with the returned output.

Possibly related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938094/git-how-to-check-which-files-exist-and-their-content-in-a-shared-bare-repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the NULL character is lost (or ignored), as if the listing includes "app" and "httpd", it will match the string "apphttpd".

So I've gone with calling "git ls-tree" multiple times for now to see if each individual file exists.

```
if [ `git ls-tree -d --name-only master "$F" | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
fi
```